# php script scanning the parent directory instead of the one its located in when php required

Tags: php, arrays, apache, file, require

Ok so i have a directory full of photos.

within that directory i have this script:

```
<?php


// These files will be ignored
$excludedFiles = array (
  ''
);

// These file extensions will be ignored
$excludedExtensions = array (
'html',
'htm',
'php',
'css'
);

// Make sure we ignore . and ..
$excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

// Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] =  strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i]));
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] = strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

// Loop through directory
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extn = explode('.',$file);
  $extn = array_pop($extn);
  // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
  if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) && !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
    $count++;
    print("<a href='#' rel='" . $file . "' class='image'><img src='" . $file . "' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>");
    }
  }
  ;
  closedir($handle);
 }

?>
```

it creates a list of the anchors for a gallery script so they images dont have to be added one by one, so its being called from a script in the parent directory of this file and the photos, so instead of making an array of the files in the /gallery folder it lists the favicon (the only image in the site root)

any ideas how i can either tell this to make a list inside the gallery directory instead of site root where the document its being called in is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `if ($handle = opendir('.')) {` with `if ($handle = opendir('./gallery/')) {`

Comment: wow im an idiot, i had tried that before posting and it didnt work, but i figured what the hay and tried it again, and after v iew source i figured out why! `<a href="#" rel="photo1.jpg"` all i had to add to make it work was in my print statement added the /gallery to the script so it would be `rel='./gallery/" . $file . "'`

Good stuff!